# How do I create an 8 sided die from one object?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Simply put, is there a way to make a cube balance solely on one point/vertex?

I'm struggling. I do not want to have to join two objects, nor have to extrude an object. I just want to have a simple eight-sided die created with one mesh.

Comment: If you look at [these google image results](https://www.google.com/search?q=eight+sided+dice&safe=active&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=941&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CB0QsARqFQoTCP6d_MaDjcYCFUJWkgodgZMAjA), you will see that it is simply two pyramids joined at the base.

Comment: I know, but I don't want to join two objects, because I've had a lot of problems with that in the past.

Comment: You can add a cube, go into edit mode, add a loop cut (ctrl+r), and merge the top and bottom faces into one vertex. I can post an answer

Comment: That shape called octahedron, you can bevel the cube with a value of 1 and remove doubles.

Comment: A cube balancing on one point is still a cube and it still only has six faces.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Cube has 4-sided faces, and octahedron has 8 faces

Comment: @Denis Yes, and a cube has *six* four-sided faces. But the question header asks for an eight-sided die and then says, "Simply put, is there a way to make a cube balance solely on one point/vertex?" I'm pointing out that a cube balancing on one of its vertices is not a simple eight-sided die because it still has the same six sides it had when it wasn't balancing on a point.

Comment: oops, thanks for correcting me people! derp

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Start by adding a cube, entering edit mode, and scaling the whole thing on the `Z` axis by `1.5` (depends on desired result). Now that you are in edit mode, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and click to add a horizontal loop cut. You can now select the top and bottom faces and merge them into one vertex each to make the point (select verts/faces/edges and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> *> At Center*).

[image: EightSidedDie GIF]

Comment: The precise Z axis scaling factor you need, in order to get a perfectly symmetrical octahedron with this method, is sqrt(2) ≈ 1.4142.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Exactly. I think I accidentally used `2` in my GIF example, thus the scaling

Answer (score 24):

In user preferences (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>) go to "Addons" and enable "Add Mesh:Extra Objects".

[image]

Back on the 3D viewport press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> Add->Mesh->Math Function-> Solid

and select Octahedron from the toolbar.

[image]

Comment: lol, straight to the goal, i like it

Answer (score 22):

You can create an Octahedron from a cube, that is its dual polyhedron:

1. Add a new cube, then in edit mode select all using <kbd>A</kbd> button.
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, input value 1 and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and select Remove Doubles.

Comment: Thanks! That's quite useful if you just want an even octahedron

Comment: Wow!!! Ultra fast method!