# How do I create a 10-sided die as one object?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, geometry

What I'm looking to do is create a 10-sided die, specifically in the shape of a 'pentagonal trapezohedron', i.e., a polyhedron that has 10 kite shaped sides.

With the following link I was able to produce a d4, d6, d8, d12, d20, & d30:
[How do I create an 8 sided die from one object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32410/how-do-i-create-an-8-sided-die-from-one-object)

What I'm looking for is something similar for a 10-sided die.

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Fastest manual method for me so far, can be done under a minute with ease (faster if the settings in operators have been pre-saved):

1. Add a *Cone* with such settings:

   [image]
2. Select the base vertices (<kbd>Z</kbd> for wireframe mode), move them `1.0` units up in Z, hit <kbd>.</kbd> for 3D cursor *Pivot center*, duplicate all with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and rotate with <kbd>R</kbd> 180°. Remove doubles with <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>. This is what you should have:

   [image]
3. Select every other vertex on the perimeter and the bottom vertex. Move `0.19` units up in Z.

   [image]
4. Select all faces, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to merge to quads. For *Max Shape Angle* input 50°:

   [image]
5. Center the thing in object mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> *Origin To Geometry* and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>. You are done with the dice:

   [image]

Comment: If you choose "Triangle fan" as the base fill type instead of "Nothing" you can even skip the duplicate, rotate and merge steps in 2.

Comment: @OliverGiesen very true, so it can be done even faster :)

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure how to model that with the least amount of steps, it might have a simple answer but i've added a solution after the code section anyway.

The [wikipedia page of Pentagonal_trapezohedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_trapezohedron) links to a [.wrl file](http://www.georgehart.com/virtual-polyhedra/vrml/pentagonal_trapezohedron.wrl) file but Blender fails to import it (for reasons that are not important here). The coordinates in the wrl are enough to build the *script* below. This could be added to the Mesh Extra objects addon, but for now just run the script from the TextEditor

```
# be in object mode with nothing selected.

import bpy

Verts = [
    0.5257311, 0.381966, 0.8506508,
    -0.2008114, 0.618034, 0.8506508,
    -0.6498394, 0, 0.8506508,
    0.5257311, -1.618034, 0.8506508,
    1.051462, 0, -0.2008114,
    0.8506508, 0.618034, 0.2008114,
    -0.5257311, 1.618034, -0.8506508,
    -1.051462, 0, 0.2008114,
    -0.8506508, -0.618034, -0.2008114,
    0.2008114, -0.618034, -0.8506508,
    0.6498394, 0, -0.8506508,
    -0.5257311, -0.381966, -0.8506508,
]

Faces = [
    3,0,1,2,
    0,3,4,5,
    1,0,5,6,
    2,1,6,7,
    3,2,7,8,
    4,3,9,10,
    5,4,10,6,
    7,6,11,8,
    3,8,11,9,
    10,9,11,6,
]

def deflate(x, stride):
    return [x[i: i + stride] for i in range(0, len(x), stride)]

Verts = deflate(Verts, 3)
Faces = deflate(Faces, 4)


mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("Base_Data")
mesh.from_pydata(Verts, [], Faces)
mesh.update()

obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Pentagonal_Trapezohedron", mesh)

scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.objects.link(obj)
obj.select = True
```

[image]

#### Manual way

---

This is based on trigonometric principles, but not perfect. Blender is an Arts package which only aims to approach visual accuracy not numeric accuracy.

- add a dodecahedron with the *Mesh Extra Objects* add-on
- notice its sides are built using two faces: 1 quad (trapezoid), 1 triangle (isosceles)
- the quads have a long edge and an opposing shorter edge.
- the long edge can be copied and placed at the tip of the short edge to get 1 'terminator' point
- repeat this process on the opposite face to find the 2nd 'terminator'.
- then edge-fill around.
- optional cleanup: *Remove Doubles*, followed by a *Limited dissolve*  and you'll get nice Kite shaped quads.

[image]

The edges in blue above are marked to show that they are the same edge, with the same length.

here's the opposite side using orange to show the corresponding edges:

[image]

Comment: Great answer! To nit-pick, the only thing you can improve, is that the manual way brings to faces that aren't 100.00% flat.

Comment: @Carlo thanks for pointing that out. I 'll think about a different approach.

Comment: @Carlo, perhaps you wish to examine the alternative. I think it doesn't suffer from the same problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a look ASAP. I agree with you in saying that high numerical precision should not be one of Blender's goal. I was amazed by the fact that extruding the faces of the default dodecahedron by 1 unit (not 1.02, or 0.7563..., but a 1.000) would leads to the perfect result. Sadly it was not, but it gets incredibly close to that anyway!

Comment: I think it's 0.9822 , but with rounding it's only going to get so close :)

Answer (score 7):

Even faster:

0) Assure 3D cursor to (0,0,0) (<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>)

[image: 3D Cursor Location: 0,0,0]

1) Add a Cone with 5 sides, depth 2.0, radius 2.25 (+/- to taste) (<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd>, Open Tool Shelf <kbd>T</kbd>)

[image: Cone: 5 sides, 2.0 depth, ~2.25 radius][image: 5 Sided cone]

2) Duplicate it (<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and rotate the duplicate 180º around X ( <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> )

[image: 2 Cones overlapped]

3) Select the first cone, Add a Boolean Modifier, Intersect the second cone, Apply.

[image: Boolean Modifier on Intersect]

4) Delete the second cone. ( <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> )

[image: Completed Pentagonal Trapezohedron]

Done.

This is by far the fastest and most accurate method I've found (this is the sixth one!) -- it takes about 30 seconds!  Vary the radius on the cone to get more or less sloped faces. 2.25 seems about like a d10.