# a 27 sided dice

Tags: modeling

I'm not a master blender user I'm just using it to make things to 3D print.
For my DND games, because I usually play chaotic neutral, I decided to make a dice with faces on it and use that to make more chaotic decisions. My friends then sugested I should be extra chaotic by making a non-standard dice shape. A 27 sided dice. Trouble is I can't even find a 27 sided 3D shape let exists let alone instructions how to model one. I found a post here
[How to model 14,16 and 18 sided dice?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111069/how-to-model-14-16-and-18-sided-dice)
that included code to generate any side dice but I didn't even know you could code in blender let alone how to implement their code to do what I want to do. I just what my chaos dice. Is anyone able to tell me what I need to do?

Comment: Have updated script in linked question for blender 2.8.  Select and copy the script, paste it into the text editor, run script  to create a 23 sided dice.  https://pasteall.org/pic/814cc58f7127475989d6dd2d9f2cabc5

Comment: text editor? I don't know what you mean because I placed a text object and it didn't work