# d100 dice - Basic mesh to start

Tags: mesh

I'm looking to create a model for a d100 (100 sided dice), hopefully planning to try and 3D print. I am wondering if there's an effective way to create a 100 sided object? I basically need an icosphere, but to be able to somehow configure the number of sides?

I'll then create text and add to each face. I know how to do this, but any additional suggestions on an efficient method would also be appreciated.

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Could use the method here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102702/15543  makes a hole or flattens N equally distributed points on a sphere  (or make a convex hull from the points)  possibly needs to be the size of a soccer ball to read without confusion.  Would seriously consider using two 10 sided die.

Comment: Ok interesting! That solution would be so far ahead of what I would be able to come up with! I will give it a try when i get a chance. Yeh I am kind of aware that this print may end up comically large but am still willing to give it a go. May be funny to roll such a big die haha

Comment: [This answer  from @batFINGER](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102702/35559) may be of interest.. I guess it may choke at 100 faces, though..

Comment: It certainly choked my system trying for 100. Would investigate finding a data set rather than calculating.  Coincidentally this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157822/euler-rotation-on-a-unit-sphere has 101 points and a link.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a 100 faces icosphere. At subdiv 2 you've got 80 faces, and at subdiv 3 you've got 320 faces.

What you can do is add a subdiv 3 icosphere, then add a Decimate modifier to it. Adjust the Ratio parameter until Face Count is 100. That wont be a nice dice however, cause some faces will be larger than others, and with different forms, so the odds of each face wont be equal.

[This set](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2781185) include a D100, maybe you could use it as a base.

Comment: Interesting idea about the decimate, I will try that when i get a chance. Depending how uneven the sides are it could still make an interesting solution. Had a look at the link, unfortunately the d100 die in this set is a more traditional 10 sided dice that is used to give the '10s' value when rolling two 10 sided dice (traditional way to give 1 in 100). Thanks for feedback