# source for The Mesh extra objects addon in latest version?

Tags: mesh, objects

Been trying to make dice using this: [How do I create an 8 sided die from one object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32410/how-do-i-create-an-8-sided-die-from-one-object/169496#169496)

But I can't find the menu where you choose the shape of the object! Does anyone know how to do this in the latest version?

Would appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the preferences (*Edit > Preferences*).
   [image: Preferences]
2. Switch to the *Add-ons* tab, search for *Extra Objects* and enabled the *Add Mesh: Extra Objects* add-on.
   [image: Enabled the add-on]
3. Add a new *Regular Solid* object (*Add > Mesh > Math Function > Regular Solid*).
   [image: Add a regular solid]
4. Open the *Adjust Last Operation* panel in the lower left corner of the 3D View.
   [image: Open the Adjust Last Operation panel]
5. Adjust the properties.
   [image: Adjust the properties]